# How to don't highlighting some ListView columns

Tags: c#, wpf

I have ListView control, where I displaying some binded multicolumn data. When user click to some row, all of the columns is highlighting. How to exclude first column from this highlight?

Comment: What control is in that column?  Just set the background to some color other than transparent.

Comment: This control is Image